# Customize paper_trail version method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I'm looking to use paper_trail in my Rails 5 application. I've used it in other Rails applications I've developed, but I'm trying to use it on a model which has the following attributes: `id`, `version`, `published`, `json`, and a few others.

The problem is paper_trail's `version` method conflicts with (and overrides) the version attribute of the class I'm using it on. So while I get a paper_trail record when I create or edit that model, I no longer get the version saved in the model record.

I know you can customize the table name (`post_versions` instead of `versions`, etc) with paper_trail, but does anyone know if there's a way to customise the name of the `version` method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its there read this https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#configuration

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that. I think I saw 'Postgres' and skimmed over it ;)